# How to push message from server to client using SignalR

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, objective-c, signalr

I am creating group chat application in iOS. so in client side (iOS) we are integrated signalR framework. In server side i am integrating signalR framework in ASP.Net.

My doubt is, i want to send the chat message from server to iPhone. so in server side i am creating an ASP.Net SignalR Hub. how to send messages from server to client (iPhone).

```
// in server side i am writing like this

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Web;    
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;    
namespace ProjectName    
{    
    public class ChatHub : Hub    
    {    
        #region Data Members

        public void Connect(string myData)    
        {    
            var id = Context.ConnectionId;

            // send to caller    
            Clients.Caller.onConnected(myData);

            // send to all except caller client    
            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(myData));     
        }
  
        public void SendMessageToAll(string myData)     
        {      
            // Broad cast message      
            Clients.All.messageReceived(myData);     
        }
  
        public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)     
        {       
            string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;
   
            if (toUserId!= null && fromUserId !=null)        
            {           
                // send to            
                Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, message); 

                // send to caller user         
                Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUserId,message);        
            }     
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)   
        {           
            var id = Context.ConnectionId;
       
            Clients.All.onUserDisconnected(id);

            return base.OnReconnected();        
        }

        public void SendMessageToGroup(string myData)   
        {         
            groupID = "1";
     
            Clients.Group(groupID).getMessages(myData);        
        }
     
        #endregion

    }    
}
```

Comment: You clearly have not put enough effort into understand how signalr works, as Mike stated, you have already sent your message to the clients, you need find a library for IOS that handles client side messages from a signalr hub.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Actually you already did it.

```
public Task SendMessage(string message)
{
    Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).MessageReceived(message);
}
```

Now you need to listen "MessageRecieved" in your client hub proxy.

And if the app is backgrounded and if SignalR still connected (that's a big IF) you can send a local notification (in iOS devices)

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotificationalloc] init]; 
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

[Read more about local notifications](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. but my doubt i want to send message from server to mobile devices. so plz tell me how to send message from server to mobile device. actually i already doing google search.in google having lot of code available for web application. but i want to send mobile app

Comment: I guess your question is about sending push notifications to mobile devices. If it's true, so you you can't use SignalR for the purpose. Make some research about PushSharp or similar libraries

Comment: thanks for your response. but my iOS developer implementing chat application in ios.. so iam maintaining server using asp.net.my doubt is i want to send chat message to iPhone device.so for chat purpose i am integrating SignalR framework.

Comment: i don't want local or push notification.. i want to send chat message from server to client..

Comment: I already answered this question my friend. You're answer is what I said in first part of my answer. I think you should read more articles about how SignalR works